# MaterilaUI Table Pagination Next button not enabling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, pagination

When I Try to search a record with lesser value that is if record are only let assume 6 or 14 or 19 or 20 the Next button does not enables but if the records are large it works totally fine

i am not sure what i am doing wrong can any one help me out

```
clear = () => {
        this.setState({
          Name: '',
          lastName: '',
          
        });
        this.props.clearSearch();
        
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Clear Redux was notgetting called